# UIAlertController giving an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup

I am new on IOS. I have a sample project and trying to learn Obj-C on that.

Now I am on the stage that is about learning how to use UIAlertController. 
And I have a code like that:

```
if (loanAmount == 0) { 

 UIAlertController *ErrorMessage    =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Invalid amount" message:@"Enter a valid number"   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]; 
   } else 
 { // sets labels
  self.interestLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%i%c",interestRate,percentage];   
self.periodLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i months",months]; 
self.totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%i",(loanAmount + tinterest)];
```

========================================================================

But When I run the simulator. There should be pop up message on Simulator. Instead of that, there is an error that says:

```
015-10-11 13:56:39.985 iBank[8055:1231178] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x7ca82400>)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
if (loanAmount == 0) { 
UIAlertController * ErrorMessage = [UIAlertController
                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"Invalid amount"
                          message:@"Enter a valid number" 
                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction 
        actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                {
                  NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                }];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction 
        actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                {
                  NSLog(@"OK action");
                }];

[ErrorMessage addAction:cancelAction];
[ErrorMessage addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController: ErrorMessage animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
 else
 {
  self.interestLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%i%c",interestRate,percentage];   
self.periodLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i months",months]; 
self.totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%i",(loanAmount + tinterest)];
  }
```

Comment: I have another quest. for you. When I click the 'OK' on pup-op message, the keyboard is going up again. So how I dismiss the keyboard after clicking 'OK'?

Comment: When I click the "OK" on pup-op message --? question for what

Comment: @symynme21 ---> your question is not clear , can you clearly say what i do for you

Comment: There are 2 items on the simulator side by side and There is a keyboard that comes up automatically for each item. When I click Submit, It shows me the pop-up message that you already did. And also When I click 'OK' on the pop-up message, The keyboard comes up again and I can not click the another item because of the keyboard. So How do I remove the keyboard on the screen to pass the another item?

Comment: See this 2 items,I have something like this:
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-MOlHuy6QaGY/UPTvZ83yy8I/AAAAAAAAB7Q/hVCFyycX_UU/s1600/8.png

Comment: this is named as **uitabbarcontroller**, see this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-quick-tip-creating-a-uitabbar-application-with-storyboards--mobile-10449